# How to convert string property to bool?

Tags: c#, string, oop, properties, boolean

I am developing a tool in `wpf`. In the tool I have the text field where I enter values. In the code for that, I have string property. Sometimes I need to enter the bool value. How can string property return bool value if it is typed true or false in text field.
Here is property:

```
public string EnvironmentValue
{
    get { return enviromentValue; }
    set
    {
        enviromentValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        AddEnviromentCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you think you can change the data type of a property on the fly?

Comment: Seems like it would be better UI to use a separate checkbox to represent your bool value.

Comment: A string property can only return a string, but you can return a string that can be parsed by a Boolean, like `bool value = bool.Parse("true");`, or you can set a string property with a bool like: `string prop = true.ToString();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to boolean in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590754/convert-string-to-boolean-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you add a checkbox instead allowing user input you avoid potential error like users typing "fasle" or "tru"

Answer (score 4):

A string property can only return a string, but you can return a string that can be parsed by a Boolean, like "true" or "false". To get the bool value from these, you can use [`bool.Parse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjM9Y27yMvdAhX3FTQIHQgiBE0QFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.boolean.parse&usg=AOvVaw33L-9uBCNtOYTN1Bh3PhhP) or [`bool.TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjlluuwyMvdAhUjLX0KHQRvCUcQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.boolean.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw3eeHXFuldMAhM4EN2TMD3E), like:

```
bool value = bool.Parse(EnvironmentValue);
```

And you can set a string property with a bool like:

```
EnvironmentValue = true.ToString();
```

But a better idea might be to use a control that was built for Boolean values, like a `CheckBox` or a `RadioButton, when you would just do something like:

```
DogLover = chkLikesDogs.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you got true and false you can use

```
bool s = Convert.ToBoolean("true");
```