# How to set a checkbox based on a string

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a function which reads some data from a txt file and than writes the data into my project.

My problem is that i can't fill my checkboxes because they don't recognize strings.

For example

```
CheckBox1.IsChecked = File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(0).Take(1).First();
```

It says that a string can't be converted into a bool value.

The first line in my txt file is obviously false in this example so the Output is not the problem.

Comment: what's the expected / actual content of the 1st line of your file?

Comment: IsChecked expects bool, but you are assigning the second line of the file and it will be of type string. if second line is boolean then you need to parse it by bool.Parse().

Comment: the actual content is false.

Comment: @ArjunVachhani Out of curiosity, why do you think it is the second line that is being parsed ?

Comment: @AnuViswan maybe it is the first character of the second line

Comment: @ArjunVachhani Do not think so. ReadLines returns a IEnumerble<String>. Skip(0).Take(1).First() should be equivalent to First()

Comment: you are right, it is the first character of first line, Skip(0).Take(1) will return first line. .First() will return the first character of string ie first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one of these two ways:

```
CheckBox1.IsChecked = bool.Parse(File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(0).Take(1).First());

CheckBox1.IsChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(0).Take(1).First())
```

mind this only works if your text from the file is always only "true" or "false", if it can be anything else use `TryParse` instead

see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/49590872/559144

Comment: `File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(0).Take(1).First()` really? what's the purpose of that `Skip(0)` how about `File.ReadLines(filename).First()`

Comment: And you don't know the content of the first line, so are you sure it can be parsed into `bool`?

Comment: @fubo, i am just re-using the code in the question and showing how to cast string to bool, if you read my warning about how to handle other input than true or false as well as the fact the opener mentions the value he gets from the file is 'false', my answer is correct as shows how to convert.

Comment: This was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't read the value in a string and after compare this one if this value equal True or False, like:

```
List<string> myLines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Temp\\MyFile.txt").ToList();
bool isChecked = false;
string myValue = myLines.FirstOrDefault();
if(myValue != null && myValue.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    isChecked = true;

CheckBox1.Checked = isChecked;
```

Like this you code is clean and safe !

Comment: Or with a lot less redundancy: `CheckBox1.IsChecked = "true".Equals(File.ReadLines("C:\\Temp\\MyFile.txt").FirstOrDefault(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: @Clemens: I don't agree with your shortcut because you start from a unknow string, it can be null), second File.ReadLines can have an Eception for multiple reason

Comment: Read it again, carefully: `"true".Equals(somethingThatCanValidlyBeNull)` will always work. And where are you catching an exception in your sample? Also note that besides it is pointless to use `List<T>` at all, the null-conditional `?.` in `myLines?.Count` makes no sense. If execution reaches that line, `myLines` can not be null.

Comment: You right, I removed the null-conditional.