# How to make the BackColor stay same after the app is closed?

Tags: c#, roblox

I made an ROBLOX Exploit and made a Theme System. Its on a menustrip. Customize > Theme > Default (Orange), Light and Dark.

When you click one of these Colors it triggers these codes:

```
private void defaultOrangeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
        panel1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        button1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        button2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        button3.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        button5.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        menuStrip1.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        panel3.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
```

that was the code for Default (Orange).

So my question is: When i want to use it in Dark Mode i click the Dark option. But after i close and open the app, it goes back to Orange (Default Color). How can i make the dark color stay after i close and open?

Comment: You need some kind of [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)). Meaning, you have to store something somewhere outside your program. An option would be to store a bool (or enum value) indicating if your program should use dark mode or light mode, and on startup check it and apply the correct theme

Comment: how can i do that store thing. im not a pro :p @MindSwipe

Comment: There are a ton of different ways, formats and targets to store things in programming. You could write "true" or "false" into a text file and [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49590754/9363973) to a boolean. Or you could use JSON to store an object containing the theme value and write it to disk. Or if you want to go absolutely overkill for this, you could use a database. All of these (and a lot more) have they're own unique benefits and drawbacks as well as different use cases. I recommend you start with something simple (write to disk) and google how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a text file and read the contents of it in C# and if it says its some theme then set the back colors. I know its a very bad method but it should work