# How to parse Y from a string as a true boolean

Tags: c#, parsing, boolean

Why does this c# code not work? I cannot figure it out.

I am struggling with finding a simple c# code example that can convert/parse string values "y" and "n" from console.readline() to boolean true or false statements and save this as a boolean data type.

```
using System;

public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input y");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "y")
        {
            bool InputY = bool.Parse(answer);
            Console.WriteLine("You have saved a 'True' statement in the boolean with name of 'InputY'");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Any random text");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `bool InputY = answer == "y";`

Comment: Because `"y"` is not a valid Boolean literal string. It would have to be `"True"` (`Boolean.TrueString`) or `"False"` (`Boolean.FalseString`), as it says [in the documentation for `Boolean.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to boolean in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590754/convert-string-to-boolean-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Boolean.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=net-6.0) (selective quotes):

> #### Returns
>
> `Boolean`
>
> true if value is equivalent to [`TrueString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.truestring?view=net-6.0); false if value is
> equivalent to [`FalseString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.falsestring?view=net-6.0).
>
> #### Exceptions
>
> `FormatException`
>
> `value` is not equivalent to [`TrueString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.truestring?view=net-6.0) or [`FalseString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.falsestring?view=net-6.0).

[Boolean.TrueString Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.truestring?view=net-6.0)

> #### Remarks
>
> This field is equal to the string `"True"`.

[Boolean.FalseString Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.falsestring?view=net-6.0)

> #### Remarks
>
> This field is equal to the string `"False"`.

As you can see `Parse` only accepts the strings `"True"` or `"False"`, it's not what you need.

But ... you are already on the branch that deals with truthy input `if (answer == "y")` so you do not need to do any other kind of parsing.

You could do something like this:

```
if (anwser.ToLower() == "y")
{
    // deal with answer yes
}
else if (answer.ToLower() == "n")
{
   // deal with answer no
}
else
{
   // deal with answer outside of y/n
}
```

If you want to have a boolean representing their answer then similarly you can create a function:

```
bool ParseYNString(string stringToParse)
{
    if (stringToParse.ToLower() == "y")
       return true;

    if (stringToParse.ToLower() == "n")
       return false;

    throw new FormatException(/* message */);
}
```

You can go one step further and create a function to get the Y/N input:

```
bool GetYNFromConsole(string prompMessage, string tryAgainMessage)
{
    Console.Write(prompMessage);

    while (true)
    {
       string line = Console.ReadLine();

       if (line.ToLower() == "y")
           return true;

       if (line.ToLower() == "n")
           return false;

       Console.Write(tryAgainMessage);
    }
}
```

That is of course just a starting point. You should customize it to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you can put just

```
bool InputY = answer == "y";
```

if you are looking for elaborated design, you can extract a method:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, bool> s_KnownBools = 
  new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    // Add all synonyms for "true" here
    { "y", true },
    { "yes", true },
    { "t", true },
    { "true", true },
    // Add all synonyms for "false" here
    { "n", false },
    { "no", false },
    { "f", false },
    { "false", false },
}; 

private static bool TryParseBool(string value, out bool result) =>
  s_KnownBools.TryGetValue(value?.Trim() ?? "", out result);

private static bool ReadBool(string title) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    if (TryParseBool(Console.ReadLine(), out bool result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid answer. PLease, try again.");
  }
}
```

then you can use it as

```
public static void Main() {
  bool inputY = ReadBool("Input y");

  if (answer) {
    Console.WriteLine("You have saved a 'True' statement in the boolean with name of 'InputY'");
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("You have saved a 'False' statement in the boolean with name of 'InputY'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

bool.Parse(string) expects the string to be "true" or "false".
You are still passing it "y", which cannot be parsed as true or false.

InputY could simply be set as

```
InputY = answer == "y";
if (InputY)
{
    Console.WriteLine("...");
}
```